# How to get iTunes to play an iPhone playlist automatically when connected to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, automator, playlist

I have a habit of working/studying while listening to music. And since the Mac I am connected to at work doesn't have all the songs I want, I normally listen to the songs via iTunes from the iPhone Playlists option.

For this, everytime I connect my iPhone to the computer, iTunes detects it, then I have to manually goto the 'iPhone' button in the application, and then "On my iPhone", and then select the playlist, and play a song.

Is there anyway of automating this process ? What I'm looking for, is as soon as I connect my iPhone, iTunes should open the playlist inside my iPhone automatically, and start playing a song at random.

Answer (score 1):

Ha !! I figured it out !! 
And then I created an applet that would do this for me using AppleScript.

And then, I published the steps/code for the same on my blog below. Here's the link ::

[How to start playing songs from your iOS device automatically on your Mac](http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/start-playing-songs-from-your-ios-playlist-on-itunes-automatically/)